# How to solve the "cannot find -lidn ,-l***"?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile

These are my error messages:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lidn
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrtmp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnettle
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgnutls
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgssapi_krb5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lkrb5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lk5crypto
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcom_err
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llber
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lldap
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:52: recipe for target 'stratum' failed
```

and I did not find any of these libraries inside `/usr/lib`, it means do I need to download some libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker is not able to find these libraries. If you have these libraries installed already then just give `-L<path to the library>` in your compilation command.

If you have not installed these libraries, then install them with the command

```
sudo apt-get install libidn
sudo apt-get install librtmp
sudo apt-get install lib<your library name>
```

Comment: thanks, I'm searching for the libraries. As you said,I need to install them now

Answer (score 0):

The usual fix (supposed you have these libraries installed) is to add one or more `-L<path>` flags to tell the linker where these should be looked up.

> ... it means I need to download some lib?

Yes, you need to install these.

Given `-l***` the linker will search for `lib***.a` (or an OS dependent equivalent) in these directories.

Comment: I don't have these lib,but where can i find these lib? Or how to find ?
i try "sudo apt-get install idn",and "make" again,
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lidn....
same error message

Comment: @iuoui Sorry I don't know either. You may find hints about that in the readme file of the software package you want to install, or at the website where you got that from.